# What method of modifying find conditions is most readable and preferred?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I often create small functions in my Models and Behaviors that add extra conditions to the `array` of a find operation in CakePHP, and I keep thinking of three possible was of implementing those functions. It seems to always come down to three possible code patterns.

I'll demonstrate these three patterns using the a function called `limitErrorCount` that will add an extra rule for find queries.

### Pattern #1: Argument and Return

```
public function limitErrorCount(array $conditions)
{
    $conditions['AND'][] = 'Document.errors <'=>10;
    return $conditions;
}

$conditions = array(....);
$conditions = limitErrorCount($conditions);
$records = $this->find('all',$conditions);
```

### Pattern #2: Pass By Reference

```
public function limitErrorCount(array &$conditions)
{
    $conditions['AND'][] = 'Document.errors <'=>10;
    return $conditions;
}

$conditions = array(....);
limitErrorCount($conditions);
$records = $this->find('all',$conditions);
```

### Pattern #3: Return and Merge

```
public function limitErrorCount()
{
    $conditions = array('AND'=>array('Document.errors <'=>10));
    return $conditions;
}

$conditions = array(....);
$conditions = Hash::merge($conditions,limitErrorCount());
$records = $this->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions));
```

All three patterns work.

I am wondering which method is best out of the three, and maybe some expert PHP insight as to why it's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice idea, I would like to see implement it in a chain-able way like in jQuery

```
$cnd = $this->Document->filterFreshOnes()->filterStarred()->filterByDaysAge('3');
$res = $this->Document->find('all', array('conditions'=>$cnd);
```

but that will require holding it in the model variable, which may backfire in cases where you forgot there is already some filter already... ;(

Comment: This seems like a comment, as opposed to an answer.

Comment: The model could create a class called `FindConditions` which has chain-able methods and a `getAsArray()` final method.